# Simple 'notify me' email registration?

Tags: html

My website is still underconstruction and I want to add a simple box for visitors to type in their email address to get notified when the website is launched.

I'm not running any cms at the moment, just a simple html webpage.  I know basic html and would appreciate step-by-step explanation to any solution suggested.

The website address is: http://aaa.sr/

Thanks!

Comment: Thats a wide question, don't you think? What server do you have? Windows? Linux? Do you know *any* programming language? PHP? Ruby? C#? Java? Without one of those, it'll be hard to guide you.

Comment: You'll need either PHP, ASP, or any language to save the mails submitted.

Comment: Thanks Nate and LaGrandMere for your replies. Now I know that there is no 'simple' answer to my question, but with your help I'm a step closer.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is that this can't be done with a standalone html page.

HTML is a markup language, which basically means it defines how information is displays.  It does not do any backend processing of information entered by the user.  You need a server-side language like PHP or ASP.NET to actually process user input.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using purely html.